# Cant update content of HTML field after click event

Tags: jquery, html

`$(".register_title.form").html(title);` part doesn't update relevant fields as expected because I'm doing something wrong!

Also can I do this in shorter way because it doesn't look nice since I repeat lines.

Thanks

**JQUERY:**

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    $("#school_left_box").click(function()
    {
        var title = $(".register_title").val();

        $("#hidden_registration_type").html('School');
        $(".register_title.form").html(title);
        $("#register_right_box").fadeIn(300);
    });

    $("#representative_left_box").click(function()
    {
        var title = $(".register_title").val();

        $("#hidden_registration_type").html('Representative');
        $(".register_title.form").html(title);
        $("#register_right_box").fadeIn(300);
    });
});
```

**HTML:**

```
<div id="school_left_box">
    <p class="register_title">School</p>
</div>

<div id="representative_left_box">
    <p class="register_title">Representative</p>
</div>

<p class="register_title form">Hello</p>
```

Comment: `.val()` is for the value of input fields. `.register_title` is not an input.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to remove this

```
    var title = $(".register_title").val();
```

By this

```
    var title = $(".register_title").text();
```

.val() is used for elements such as input, select and textarea: 
[.val() documentation](http://api.jquery.com/val/)

Comment: One last thing. Since `.register_title` is a class and has repetitions, is there any way of just getting content of current clicked title. Currently the output is this: `SchoolRepresentativeHello`

Comment: @MadMax `var title = $(".register_title", this)` is equivalent to `var title = $("this").find('.register_title')` which (should be pretty clear) will search and select only in the element that was clicked

Comment: @Spokey - Thank you `var title = $(".register_title", this);` worked fine. +1

Answer (score 0):

If it is input

```
var title = $(".register_title").val();
```

if it is not an input

```
var title = $(".register_title").text();
```